# Применение оператора noexcept и изменение такового в следующих стандартах

Tags: c++, исключения, c++11

1. Достаточно ли в клиентском коде, не требующем особой оптимизации компилятора в вопросе генерируемых исключений, в случае *гарантии отсутствия исключений* писать `noexcept`, а в противном случае ничего не писать? Например, это условное выражение:
   `noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<from_json_fn>().call(j, val, priority_tag<1> {})))` не очень приятно выглядит в коде, не претендующем на высший уровень оптимизации механизма исключений, да и получается копипаста большая. Насколько я просмотрел стандартную библиотеку, там таких `noexcept`-спагеттей не наблюдается.
2. В каких случаях такие вещи вообще применимы? Если надо побыстрей?
3. Ожидается ли новый proposal к следующему стандарту, после которого можно будет писать нечто такое: `noexcept(auto)` и не писать такие длинные уродливые конструкции?

Comment: Не очень понимаю, на что должен опираться `auto` в этом контексте. Проверить все функции внутри?

Comment: @alexout Например, проверить на noexcept все функции и операторы внутри. Не знаю только, как реагировать на исключения, съедаемые catch блоком в самой функции.

Comment: `noexcept` не гарантирует отсутствие исключений в функции, которая помечена соответствующим спецификатором. Она (как и те функции, которые в ней вызываются) по-прежнему может выбрасывать исключения, но вместо раскрутки стека при этом будет происходить немедленный вызов `std::terminate`.

Comment: Более того, до C++17 `noexcept`-спецификация даже не является частью типа. Вот, например, как компилируется один и тот же код в [C++14](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YA0mdWEnMs3HnTyX) и [C++17](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vyOWNaVkkac0agZc). По этой причине до C++17 нельзя было даже использовать синонимы типов с участием `noexcept`-спецификаторов.

Comment: @Constructor про часть типа спасибо, что объяснили, не знал. Мне это сведение определенно пригодится. Просто особенности стандарта 17 только начинаю прощупывать и еще не дошел до изменений в плане noexcept.